# Using greater than operator with subprocess.call

Tags: python, subprocess, call

What I am trying to do is pretty simple. I want to call the following command using python's `subprocess` module.

```
cat /path/to/file_A > file_B
```

The command simply works and copies the contents of `file_A` to `file_B` in current working directory. However when I try to call this command using the `subprocess` module in a script it errors out. Following is what I am doing:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(["cat", "/path/to/file_A", ">", "file_B"])
```

and I get the following error:

```
cat: /path/to/file_A: No such file or directory
cat: >: No such file or directory
cat: file_B: No such file or directory
```

what am I doing wrong ? How can I use the greater than operator with subprocess modules `call` command ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`>` output redirection is a *shell* feature, but `subprocess.call()` with an `args` list and `shell=False` (the default) does not use a shell.

You'll have to use `shell=True` here:

```
subprocess.call("cat /path/to/file_A > file_B", shell=True)
```

or better still, use `subprocess` to redirect the output of a command to a file:

```
with open('file_B', 'w') as outfile:
    subprocess.call(["cat", "/path/to/file_A"], stdout=outfile)
```

If you are simply copying a file, use the [`shutil.copyfile()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfile) to have *Python* copy the file across:

```
import shutil

shutil.copyfile('/path/to/file_A', 'file_B')
```

Comment: I am not exactly copying a file but extracting a part using `sed`.

Answer (score 1):

Addition to Martijn's answer:

you can do the same thing as `cat` yourself:

```
with open("/path/to/file_A") as file_A:
    a_content = file_A.read()
with open("file_B", "w") as file_B:
    file_B.write(a_content)
```

Comment: The `shutil.copyfile()` function does essentially this, but more efficiently (using a buffer instead of reading the whole file in memory).

Comment: True. Just wanted to state additional possibility.